# How to create boost::hana::map with keys being compile-time strings (C++14)?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

I have seen in the boost.hana mailing list a following example, that fails to compile:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <string>
namespace hana = boost::hana;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    constexpr auto m1 = hana::make_map(
            hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
            hana::make_pair("key2"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>)
        ); 
}
```

I get the following error on GCC 7.3.0 -std=c++14:

```
error: unable to find string literal operator ‘operator""_s’ with ‘const char [5]’, ‘long unsigned int’ arguments
             hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
                             ^~~~~~~~
```

And by the way, what is the «_s» suffix to the string literal?

Answer (score 2):

The compile-time string literal operator that Boost.Hana's [`_s`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1string.html#ad77f7afff008c2ce15739ad16a8bf0a8) is using is a gcc extension and must be enabled by defining `BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL`.

You must also import the operator into the current namespace from `boost::hana::literals`.

Alternatively, there is a macro [`BOOST_HANA_STRING`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1string.html#a7f15faa77e126e1c2b08a2224ceefb84) that can be used, but it uses a lambda and can not be constexpr in C++14.

While not finalized, C++20 will likely have this operator as well as string literals as template parameters which is exciting. ([here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0424r2.pdf))

Here is a complete example:

```cpp
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

int main() {
  constexpr auto m1 = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<void>),
    hana::make_pair("key2"_s, hana::type_c<void>)
  );

  constexpr auto m3 = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(hana::string<'k','e','y','1'>{}, hana::type_c<void>),
    hana::make_pair(hana::string<'k','e','y','2'>{}, hana::type_c<void>)
  );

  // not constexpr until C++17
  auto m2 = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(BOOST_HANA_STRING("key1"), hana::type_c<void>),
    hana::make_pair(BOOST_HANA_STRING("key2"), hana::type_c<void>)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason doesn't compile is actually the «_s» suffix. Solution: compile with `-DBOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL`.

Alternatively use `hana::string_c<'k', 'e', 'y', '1'>` in place of `"key1"_s` and `hana::string_c<'k', 'e', 'y', '2'>` in place of `"key2"_s`)

#### Explanation

This suffix is a Hana's take on non-standard C++ extension named "string literal operator template". It is available only on GCC and Clang compilers and because of that Hana's support for it disabled by default.

This extension has not made it to the standard (after multiple tries) because it constructs string types in the least efficient way - character-by-character. Including it in the standard would encourage its usage, and that would result in much-elevated compile time.

There is no other alternatives, except maybe for the trick employed by `boost::mpl::string` that use 4-byte unicode character literals in place of single-byte character literals that should cut the compilation time by four (but then you are limited to ASCII strings).